# I am a Re-Applicant for MS/PhD program,can I copy snippets of my previous SoP for my new application

Tags: masters, application, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for masters program after a gap,I had a few rejects last time and re applying to those universities this year again,will it be ok if I copy some snippets from my old SoP for the new application's SoP

Comment: Sure. Is there any reason you think you shouldn't?

Comment: Only reuse your SOP if you're sure that wasn't what caused you to be rejected last time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practice among students to do so. I applied to two schools and used almost the same statement of purpose - I just made sure that any specifics like school name and programs were tailored correctly. You should be okay, just be sure that your new essay isn't an exact duplicate of the one you sent before.